# Batch fails to deploy

Tags: apex, deployment, class, failing-tests, schedulebatch

I have a batch that I uploaded into Production successfully on July 20th and then a change to that batch on July 27th, both with no issues.

I needed to make another change to that batch today, so I made the changes and deployed it but now I'm receiving errors - all pertaining to a test class I deployed last week.

The batch I'm trying to upload creates a task to the Account Owner when a related contact has an upcoming expired license.  The test class it keeps failing at verifies if a lead owner is updated after a field has a defined value - so not related at all.

How do I go about making this work?  Am I going to run into this same issue when I deploy something else in the future, how do I go about fixing if so?

I'll be happy to provide code samples, just not sure what is/isn't relevant for you pros to see.

[image]

Comment: It will be difficult to assist without seeing the *error messages blocking your deployment*. Please include the text or a screenshot of these error messages via **[edit]**.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the errors.

Comment: Those unit tests give you no information about why they failed, so the only solution is to really dig into that class and figure out why the assignment process does not work as expected. The top error is a little bit more useful, you can look at that flow and see if it was created or modified since your most recent successful deployment. If you wrote those unit tests, this deployment is a good lesson on why using informative assertion messages are so valuable.

Comment: The worst part about the first error is that the test class it references wasn't even supposed to deploy as I received errors upon deployment when I initially tried (and didn't think I attempted to ever re-deploy it)

As for the other errors, the test works as it should on the trigger I built it for.  Do tests have to be built to provide coverage for objects/records they're not intended for?

Comment: build a sandbox from PROD and then deploy your changes into this new sandbox - test accordingly